# Setting my development, test and production environment for SharePoint 2013 server

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-enterprise

I need to set up the development environment, the test environment and the production environment for SharePoint 2013, i've read different articles from MSDN, but i didn't find hardware requirements for development and test envirenment, so my questions are :

1. what are the minimum hardware requirements for both
2. should i install them on 1 server or multiple server is recommended (what is the recommended physical architecture) ?

thanks

Answer (score 1):

Basically this thing is depend upon how to use the environment i.e. number of users, storage, type of operations, service applications etc.

MSFT mentioned the minimum hardware requirement on this [technet.](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc262485.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)

[image]

Comment: thanks for your answer, i saw this table but i think that it talkes about the production envirenment, how about the developpement and the test environments